# CSGO if my pc shut down and my team tied do I get elo?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If my pc shut down and my team tied do I get elo? Because my PC restarted in the middle of the game and then when my PC restarted my team tied the game, I didn't get banned.

Comment: Is there not a match record that you can check to see if you gained/lost elo?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the game is in your recently played matches. If it is, your ranking was affected.

Answer (score 1):

It's threaded the same way as if you left the game. You have 3 minutes to restart the PC and join the game, after that it is a "Leave" and you basically lost.

Answer (score 0):

You do gain elo, not from the entire match, but only from the rounds you played. You don't get elo from the rounds they played while you restarted your PC, but if you were still able to rejoin and play the final round, then you also get elo from that final round.

Comment: Can you include sources?